# Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple keeps showing

Tags: python, list, class, methods, tuples

so I'm writting a method, that will show me the nearest enemy.

```
ef nearestEnemy(player, *args):
    nearest = 0
    list = [args]
    print(list)
    for x in list:
        if player.getDistancetoEnemy(list[x]) > nearest:
            nearest = list[x]
```

It keeps giving me an error:

**def nearestEnemy(player, *args):
    nearest = 0
    list = [args]
    print(list)
    for x in list:
        if player.getDistancetoEnemy(list[x]) > nearest:
            nearest = list[x]**

This is my main:

```
def main():
    dragon1 = dragon()
    dragon2 = dragon()
    player1 = player()
    player1.setPosition(100, 100)
    dragon1.setPosition(200, 200)
    dragon2.setPosition(150, 150)
    nearestEnemy(player1, dragon1, dragon2)
```

This is the method that gives me distance to enemy:

```
    def getDistancetoEnemy(self, enemy):
        return math.sqrt(pow(enemy.getPosition()[0] - self.x, 2) + pow(enemy.getPosition()[1] - self.y, 2))
```

Thanks for all your help and have a wonderfull evening.

Comment: 1) Can you reformat the error to make it readale? 2) There may some problem with `for x in list:` and then `list[x]`.

Comment: 3) Having a variable with a name like `list` is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

When "*args" is used, the variable `args` is a `tuple`. Therefore, `list = [args]` will become --> `list = [(player1, dragon1, dragon2)]`

So a `for` loop is used to get the individual elements from the tuple:

```py
list = []
for arg in args:
    list.append(arg)
```

In this line:

```py
for x in list:
```

the variable `x` is a `tuple`. Hence `list[x]` fails, and you should be using indices for lookup instead of the actual element (x) in the list.

Either use `x` directly instead of `list[x]` or change your for loop condition to:

```py
for i in range(len(list))
```

and then use `list[i]`